# В jupyter notebook не влезают символы слева, как исправить?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

Учусь работать с Jupyter Notebook.
У меня почему то при выводе не влезает часть символов слева(см картинку).
Подскажите, как это можно исправить ?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52725612/jupyter-notebook-cell-output-cut-off-truncated-by-margin-caused-by-jupyter-theme

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потеря части строки вызвана использованием [jupyter-themes](https://github.com/dunovank/jupyter-themes).
Чуть подробнее о проблеме по [ссылке](https://github.com/dunovank/jupyter-themes/issues/288)

Для исправления можно в файле custom.css выбранной темы исправить параметры  div.out_prompt_overlay.prompt и  div.out_prompt_overlay.prompt:hover.

Однако в моем случае помогло просто обновление тем  и сброс кэшей

```
pip3 install jupyterthemes
pip3 install --upgrade jupyterthemes
jt -r
jt -t solarizedd
```

**UPD**
Похоже, что проблема вызвана плагином для сворачивания ячеек. Решением будет поправить файл `custom.css`. У меня путь к нему был `/home/andrey/.jupyter/custom/custom.css`.

Надо изменить у `div.out_prompt_overlay.promptс` и `div.out_prompt_overlay.promptс.hover` 
свойства `min-width` и `width`  с  14.5ex на на 11.5ex. 
[Подробнее](https://github.com/dunovank/jupyter-themes/issues/288)